# C: Hashes pyramid pattern

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop

I need a program which prints the pattern below. Program must read the number of lines from user.

***Example 1:***

**Input:** 3

**Output:**

```
#
##
####
```

***Example 2:***

**Input: ** 5

**Output**

```
#
##
####
#######
###########
```

**The code I have so far:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   int n;
   scanf("%d", &n);
   int step = n;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j+=step) {
         printf("#");
      }
      step--;
      puts("");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you try? We are not doing your homework.

Comment: I tried to use nested for loops but I'm always getting stuck at some point

Comment: Show us the code and where you get stucked, probably we can help you with a specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see from your examples the pattern is:

Line 0: 1 #

Line 1: 2 # (i.e. 1 + 1 or "The number of # in previous line + this line number")

Line 2: 4 # (i.e. 2 + 2 or "The number of # in previous line + this line number")

Line 3: 7 # (i.e. 4 + 3 or "The number of # in previous line + this line number")

So you can use "The number of # in previous line + this line number" as the pattern in your code to find the number of # needed in the current line. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int limit = 1;                      // Limit for line 0
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        limit += i;                     // Calculate limit for this line
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; ++j) {
            printf("#");
        }
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output for n=7:

```
#
##
####
#######
###########
################
######################
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing great ;)

you actually have three issues:

The first issue is that you do not want to increment j by step.
The second issue is that you are not incrementing step in the right place.
The third is that the max value of `j` is NOT `i`

Comment: No - I consider this help. Giving answers is not allowed for homework.

Comment: Notice that the correct answer above increments j by 1 instead of step, increments step inside the for loop, and changed the comparative value of j. All of which I recommended and provides the correct output.

Obviously analyzing the problem, and the solution, and their disjoint is most of the effort. Not giving the user an answer is not the same thing as not putting in effort.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

It is also mentioned here that multiple forms of help should be provided before giving a code complete solution, and that the code complete solution can be put online at a later date so that the student might have access to the full solution later after having fully tried themselves.